# How do I add these two indicators to a table so it appears in the top right corner of my chart

Tags: pine-script

Can someone please help me to add these two indicator into a table that shows up in the top right corner of the chart. Below is the script for each indicator

Indicator 1:

```
//@version=3
study("Current Candle", precision=0)
plot(100/(high - low)/100, transp=100)
```

Indicator 2:

```
//@version=3
study("Previous Candle", precision = 0)
plot(100/(high[1]-low[1])/100, transp=100)
```

[Click here for image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF6kS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script", precision=0)

plot(100/(high - low)/100, transp=100)
plot(100/(high[1]-low[1])/100, transp=100) 


curr = 100/(high - low)/100
prev = 100/(high[1]-low[1])/100


var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 2, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Current Candle " + str.tostring( math.round(curr,0)))
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 1, row = 0, text = "Previous Candle " + str.tostring(math.round(prev,0)), bgcolor=color.teal)
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you Star Lucky!